# Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution with "or more" Successes

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, hypergeometric-distribution

I understand how to calculate multivariate hypergeometric distributions.  For example, if you have an urn with 2 red marbles, 4 white marbles, 8 blue marbles, and 12 orange marbles, the probability of drawing 5 marbles and getting 1 red marble and 2 white marbles is as follows:

$P = \frac{{2 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{20 \choose 2}}{26 \choose 5}$

What I'm wondering is if I wanted to calculate 1 or more red marbles and 2 or more white marbles, if that could be calculated this way:

$P = \frac{{2 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{24 \choose 2}}{26 \choose 5}$

where I'm adding in the extra red and white marbles to the last combination. If this doesn't work (which I don't think it does because the numerator and denominator no longer match) why not, and is there a nice solution to this problem that doesn't involve summing all of the separate probabilities?

Comment: "*why not*...?" ... you already explained why not right before you asked that.

Comment: I said that I don't think it works and the reason why, not that I know for sure.  I'm not a stats expert by any means.

Comment: "Why is this wrong" would depend on why you'd think it was right. Put another way, there's no reason to expect randomly chosen manipulations are right, so if you give the reasoning why this might be expected to produce the same answer as the sum of probabilities, we might identify the flaw. If there isn't a particular reason to think so, it's a bit like saying "why isn't 5 = 7?" -- without a reason to suspect it, it's just because things that aren't equal ... aren't equal.

Comment: As for evaluation without summing: the CDF is given in the column on the right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), as you see it involves the hypergeometric function $_3F_2$, which is discussed (with other members of the generalized hypergeometric function [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).  R does it by computing the ratio of the cdf to the pmf (as a summation) "based on ideas of Ian Smith and Morten Welinder", which sounds like there's not even a reference for R's approach.

Comment: It looks like I have a lot more reading to do.  If you could outline what you think the best next steps would be (which could be just copying your comment if you think that's sufficient), I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have no direct experience of evaluating the hypergeometric CDF outside of either summing the probabilities, using an approximation (normal or binomial in different situations) or calling a function that does it, so I probably can't say much outside the comments here. I'll see what I can do.